# Width sizing on inline form in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which describes an input box, and two select boxes with their labels in an inline form, in a panel:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Opciones de búsqueda en tarea</b></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-inline searchbox">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname_new" placeholder="Buscar en el nombre o Descripción">         

      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="proyect_box"> Para el proyecto: </label>
         <select class="form-control" id="proyect_box">          
         </select>
      </div>          

      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="proyect_box"> Con el estado: </label>
         <select class="form-control" id="proyect_box">
        <option>Todos</option>
        <option>Pendiente</option>
        <option>Finalizada</option>
        <option>Frenada</option>             
         </select>
      </div>        

    </form>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
  </div>
```

I know in inline forms you are supposed to control the width of the objects themselves. So I tried writing a little css code that looks like this:

```
.searchbox{
  width: 1000px;
}
```

However, no matter what I do, I can't change the size of the input box. All I want is for the input box to have a larger width.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.searchbox is the class on the form, not on the input. If you attach an explicit width to #fname_new (the id of the input itself), you can control it better.

So instead of the css you have, use:

```
#fname_new {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Or, if you'd like all of your text inputs to have the same width, use

```
.form-control[type="text"] {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Or, if you'd like all of your form fields (select, input, etc) to have the same width, use

```
.form-control {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: The only thing that seems to work is to remove the form control class. Then the width actually changes.

Comment: Try using .form-control#fname_new { styles in here }

Comment: Never mind!! I found a mistake. First option worked!! Thank you!